# SQL Server 2017 Developer : database diagram folder missing

Tags: sql-server, database, database-diagram

I have a problem with database diagram folder.. I cannot find it anywhere. I've looked everywhere. I've downloaded sample database and used it as db owner but it didn't work.

Comment: Which version of the SQL Server **Management Studio** are you using?? It seems database diagrams is *gone* from SSMS **v18.x** - see here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/pour-one-out-for-database-diagrams-and-good-riddance/